# Как в vuex вывести данные реактивно через store в разные шаблоны

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Не могу разбросаться как выводить значения при заполнение Input в одном компоненте через store Для вывода в другом, сейчас сделал через computed, всё работает, но только если в шаблоне где происходит заполнение инпута вернуть это свойство. 
Есть дочерний компонент в котором

```
<template>

 <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="phone">
</template>
<script>
 export default {
  data(){
   return { 
        phone:''
     }
    },
   computed:{
     heroPhone(){
        this.$store.dispatch('setPhone',  this.phone)
        return this.$store.getters.getPhoneValue;
     },
   }

</script>
```

В store.js

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
    state:{
        phoneValue: '',
    },
    getters:{
      getPhoneValue: state => { return state.phoneValue }
    },
    actions:{
      setPhone(context, data){
        context.commit('setPhone', data)
    },
    mutations:{
      setPhone(state, payLoad){
        state.phoneValue = payLoad
      },
    }
  })
```

И соответственно с другом компоненте пытаюсь вывести значение phoneValue из store, в computed свойстве,

```
 computed:{
        phone(){
          return this.$store.getters.getPhoneValue
        } 
      }
```

вывожу через {{phone}} само свойство.
Но так ничего не выводится, а выводится только если в шаблоне где отлавливаю значение input

```
v-model="phone"
```

Вывести объявленное computed свойство {{heroPhone}} тогда в других шаблонах значение `store.phoneValue` отлично выводится.

Не могу понять как правильно выводить реактивно данные в разные шаблоны через vuex.

Может кто-нибудь сталкивался.

Comment: Думаю, что значение phone не устанавливается вовсе. Проверь проходят ли мутациая на setPhone.

Comment: если в компоненте в котором, отслеживаю значение и вызываю  
  
`computed:{
     heroPhone(){
        this.$store.dispatch('setPhone',  this.phone)
        return this.$store.getters.getPhoneValue;
     },`  
Не возвращаю` {{heroPhone}}`то мутация не проходит. А если возвращаю то в других компонентах значение доступно через геттер

`computed:{
            phone(){
                return this.$store.getters.getPhoneValue;

            },
}`
И в state значения вносятся. Что делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В текущем варианте компонент не вызывает никаких обработок при изменении поля phone и следственно ничего не сохраняется в store.

Собственно когда вы вместо `phone` используете `heroPhone` начинается вызваться код отвечающий за логику автопроперти, который и устанавливает значение `phoneValue` в `vuex.store`.

Для решения вашей задачи можно добавить к `heroPhone` геттер и сеттер. 
Собственно любое изменение поля ввода будет вызывать сеттер нашего `heroPhone`. 
Поэтому на любой новый символ вызывать сохранение в store избыточно, то в этом случае нам поможет [`debounce` из библиотеки lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#debounce). Если будете пользоваться ей, то не забудьте ее подключить к своему проекту.

Кратко `debounce` частые вызовы функций блокирует, оставляя только последний. В итоге в store будет записан только самый последний вариант.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data () {
            return {
                phone: ''
            }
        },
        computed: {
            heroPhone: {
            get: function () {
              return this.phone; // вернем текущее значение
            },
            set: function(value) {
             this.phone = value; // поставим новое
             this.debounceSetPhone(); // проставим новое уже в store
            }}
        },
        created() {
          // чтобы не сохранять phone на каждый ввод символа
          // будет сохранять раз в 1 секунду
          this.debounceSetPhone = _.debounce(this.setPhone, 1000)
        },
        methods:{
         setPhone() {
           //this.$store.dispatch('setPhone',  this.phone);
            console.log(this.phoneProp);
          }
        }
        
        
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
<input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="heroPhone">
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.13.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Интересно, неужели тут так важно использовать debounce? Ладно если запрос на сервер идет, но записать в store вроде не так страшно. Также могу посоветовать не ставить всю lodash заради одной функции, есть возможность ставить по одной функции, [так](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.debounce), например или можно использовать [этот](https://github.com/component/debounce) пакет

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько согласен пусть на клиенте хоть тысячу раз будет писать в стор. Да и можно найти вариант по проще или даже самостоятельно реализовать это в своем проекте. На вкус и цвет.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, вроде разобрался. Но не понял для чего использовать хук `created` у меня он не выполняется.   И ещё функция `_.debounce(this.setPhone, 1000)` тоже не работает, хотя `_each` из этой библиотеки работает. Возможно проблема  областью видимости.

Comment: `created` нужен для того чтобы привязать debounceSetPhone к методу  setPhone. Если вы подключали lodash через плагины, то нужно использовать `this.$_.debounce`